# Can I replace casein in a recipe with soy protein?

Tags: vegan, soy

I wanted to try [this veggie burger recipe](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/hi-tech-veggie-burger) from ChefSteps. However, it uses sodium caseinate as one of the binding ingredients. Casein is derived from milk, thus making the burger non-vegan.

Would directly substituting (1:1) sodium caseinate with soy protein or pea protein cause any problems?